# Can't use Cloudflare SSL certificate for website that is hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

**Aim:**

I want to use free SSL certificate on Cloudflare on the website that is current hosted on Azure.

**Background**

A `SSL certificate` has been bought from Azure, but we found that we need to upgrade our subscription before able to bind it to our website. Hence, we decided to use Cloudflare free plan that also offers SSL. The domain provider that we use is `godaddy`.

**Problem:**

I have followed the instructions [here](http://blog.guybarrette.com/post/2016/01/17/How-to-get-free-SSL-for-Azure-Web-Apps-using-Cloudflare.aspx), and now on the Cloudflare, I could see the `status` for SSL certificate as `Active Certificate`. However, when I enter the url as `https://mywebsite` (`https`), it says that `This certificate is not valid (host name mismatch)`, which is shown on the screenshot below:[image]

**Questions**

1. Why does the current SSL certificate points to `.azurewebsites.net`? Shouldn't it points to cloudflare, after changing the nameservers? What does it mean by host name mismatch?
2. Current `status` for SSL certificate on Cloudflare is `Active Certificate`, does it mean that it's verified and currently applied to the website?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at the article Troy Hunt wrote about this: [How to get your SSL for free on a Shared Azure website with CloudFlare](https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-get-your-ssl-for-free-on-shared/)

Comment: @RickvandenBosch OP's linked article seems to be a condensed version of the Troy Hunt. I originally put the bounty since I also encounter the same problem, though it resolved by itself the next day.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct, if it is configured properly it should display the correct certificate in your browser. Possible reasons that it doesn't show correctly: old certificate cached in browser, old nameservers cached, you're not using cloudflare for the appropriate DNS records.

1b. As for the host name mismatch, you typed in example.com and it returned a certificate for a different domain. This means that the data can still be encrypted during transmission but that you are probably not communicating with who you think you are.

2. Not necessarily. In the article that you link is a great diagram of this process (5th image). You are using Flexible SSL. In order for this to work your website needs to go to Cloudflare's servers first. You can have an active certificate but that doesn't mean that it's been applied to your website. Make sure that the domain and/or any subdomains are on cloudflare and that data is routed through Cloudflare's servers.

Comment: Old nameservers being cached seems to be the answer, or perhaps different DNS server caching policy. I encountered the same problem, but later found out that the problem only persisted while using Norton DNS, not when using my ISP's DNS. About a day later, everything resolves correctly.